# central limit theorem

Tags: c#, math, theory

i want to observe central limit theorem and wrote this program.But i confused that,must i observe like that.Is there any wrong ?

```
xx
xxx
xxxx
xxxxx
xxxxxx
xxx
xxxx
xxx
x
x
```

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                Func();
        }
        public static void Func()
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int[] d = new int [10];
            int sum;

            for (int k = 0; k < 5000; k++)
            {
                sum = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                    sum += r.Next(0, 10000);
                Set(d, sum/50);

            }

            DispResult(d);
        }
        private static void DispResult(int[] d)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < d[i]; j += 1000)
                {
                    Console.Write("X");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        private static void Set(int[] d, int a)
        {

            if (a > 9000)
                d[9]++;
            else if (a > 8000)
                d[8]++;
            else if (a > 7000)
                d[7]++;
            else if (a > 6000)
                d[6]++;
            else if (a > 5000)
                d[5]++;
            else if (a > 4000)
                d[4]++;
            else if (a > 3000)
                d[3]++;
            else if (a > 2000)
                d[2]++;
            else if (a > 1000)
                d[1]++;
            else
                d[0]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I asked that i hoped shape like that but i observed differently,is there any wrong or not ?

Comment: Your program produces something very close to normal distribution for me, are you sure you run the same version of source code you've posted here?

Comment: yes i ran same version because of that i confused.That is the my quesiton,is is true or not ?

Comment: What happens if you increase the sample count?

Comment: increase number of samples (50 seems too few to observe gaussian behavior at this range of numbers). also, consider changing `d/50` to `round(d/50)`

Comment: when i increased the samples i couldn't observe any different so what could i do ? I didn't understand what does it mean " changing d/50 to round(d/50) "

Comment: `d/50` is trimming to the floor value. for instance, `99/50` is 1, and not 2. use `Math.Round(d/50)` if you want the result to be 2, for this example. though I doubt it will have much affect on the outcome in this case, it is still better practice.

Comment: I tried it and it is not better than first one

Comment: I meant `Math.Round(d/50.0)` and not what I wrote above. but I still doubt it will make any difference in here.

Comment: if you are sure your way please wrote that's code because the way i understood is not different from first one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is very unclear what you're asking here but I'll take a stab at it.

Your program simulates rolling a 10000-sided die fifty times and taking the average. You then do that 5000 times and show a histogram of the results.

The Central Limit Theorem states that as the number of rolls increases, the histogram should more closely approximate a Gaussian distribution.

If what you want to do is to observe the truth of the Central Limit Theorem, then I would modify your program as follows: I would make "Func" take an integer n, the number of rolls and then have the body of Main be:

```
for(int n = 1; n < 10; ++n)
{
   Func(n);
   Console.WriteLine("-----");
}
```

Then replace all the "50"s in Func with n.

That way you are simulating rolling 1, 2, 3, 4... 10 dice and taking the average. When you plot the histograms you'll see that for 1, the histogram is rectangular and then it gets more and more bell shaped as n increases. That demonstrates the Central Limit Theorem.

Comment: I remember doing this on my TI-85 when I was bored in math class one day.  :)

Comment: Greg,what a nice entertainment.Nowadays i am being bored a lot so if you can advice something like this example to do ,i will be very pleased to you.